# How can I sort an XDocument by attribute?

Tags: c#, sorting, linq-to-xml

I have some XML

```
<Users>
    <User Name="Z"/>
    <User Name="D"/>
    <User Name="A"/>
</User>
```

I want to sort that by *Name*. I load that xml using `XDocument`. How can I view that xml sorted by Name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can sort using LINQ to Xml, if XmlDocument is not the case

```
XDocument input = XDocument.Load(@"input.xml");
XDocument output = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Users",
        from node in input.Root.Elements()
        orderby node.Attribute("Name").Value descending
        select node));
```

Comment: I do that but i have an exception. "At least one object must implement IComparable".

Comment: it needs to be `node.Attribute("Name").Value`

Comment: FYI, doing a stright `node.Attribute("Name").Value` leaves you open for a null reference exception if that attribute is missing. Also, if the XML document specifies a schema, just doing `node.Attribute("Name")` won't be enough either, as you'll have to use a proper `XName` to find the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Users",
        new XElement("Name", "Z"),
        new XElement("Name", "D"),
        new XElement("Name", "A")));

var doc = xdoc.Element("Users").Elements("Name").OrderBy(n => n.Value);
XDocument doc2 = new XDocument(new XElement("Users", doc));
```

Comment: Name is an attribute, not an element ;)