# Sorting all the XmlNode in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting, xmldocument

I have a `XML` file (XmlDocument) containing data as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <transactions>
        <transaction date="03022014" type="document">
            <document name="Page1">
                <data>
                    <document>
                        <attribute name="Position" value="4"/>
                        <attribute name="qty" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="number" value="1202"/>
                    </document>
                    <document>
                        <attribute name="Position" value="3"/>
                        <attribute name="qty" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="number" value="1203"/>
                    </document>
                    <document>
                        <attribute name="Position" value="2"/>
                        <attribute name="qty" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="number" value="1205"/>
                    </document>
                    <document>
                        <attribute name="Position" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="qty" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="number" value="1206"/>
                    </document>
                </data>
            </document>
        </transaction>
    </transactions>
</xml>
```

I want to sort the `<document>` element by "Position".
It should be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <transactions>
        <transaction date="03022014" type="document">
            <document name="Page1">
                <data>
            <document>
                        <attribute name="Position" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="qty" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="number" value="1206"/>
                    </document>
                <document>
                        <attribute name="Position" value="2"/>
                        <attribute name="qty" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="number" value="1205"/>
                    </document>
                <document>
                        <attribute name="Position" value="3"/>
                        <attribute name="qty" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="number" value="1203"/>
                    </document>
                    <document>
                        <attribute name="Position" value="4"/>
                        <attribute name="qty" value="1"/>
                        <attribute name="number" value="1202"/>
                    </document>
                 </data>
            </document>
        </transaction>
    </transactions>
</xml>
```

Is this somehow possible with `LINQ`?
I tried to solve it with `LINQ`, but it is not working

Comment: You're question is already existed in StackOverflow @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232089/how-can-i-sort-an-xdocument-by-attribute
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922180/sort-xmldocument-using-linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
var documents = xDoc.Descendants("document").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") != "Page1")
              .OrderBy(x => (int)(x.Elements("attribute").First().Attribute("value")))
              .ToList();

var data = xDoc.Descendants("data").First();
data.Remove();
var document = xDoc.Descendants("document").First(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "Page1");
document.Add(new XElement("data", documents));
xDoc.Save("path");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(path_to_xml);

XElement dataElement = xml.Descendants("data").FirstOrDefault();
if (dataElement != null)
{
    var sortedAttributeElements = dataElement.Elements("document")
                  .Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null && x.Attribute["name"] == "Position")
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("value").Value);

    var sortedDocumentElements = sortedAttributeElements.Select(x => x.Parent);
}

//replace old "data" element content with "sortedDocumentElements" and save
```